# Update SQLite database without restarting application

Tags: node.js, sqlite, cron, forever, node-sqlite3

I have an *NodeJS* application that run on a production server with *forever*.

That application use a third-party *SQLite* database which is updated every morning with a script triggered by a cron, who download the db from an external FTP to the server.

I spend some time before realising that I need to restart my server every time  the file is rapatriated otherwise there is no change in the data used by my application (I guess it's cached in memory at starting).

```
// sync_db.sh
wget -l 0 ftp://$REMOTE_DB_PATH --ftp-user=$USER --ftp-password=$PASSWORD \
  --directory-prefix=$DIRECTORY -nH
forever restart 0 // <- Here I hope something nicer...
```

What can I do to refresh the database without  restarting the app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not overwrite a database file that might have some open connection to it (see [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)).

The correct way to overwrite a database is to download to a temporary file, and then copy it to the actual database with the backup API, which takes care of proper transactional behaviour. The simplest way to do this is with the `sqlite3` command-line shell:

```
sqlite3 $DIRECTORY/real.db ".restore $DOWNLOADDIRECTORY/temp.db"
```

(If your application manually caches data, you still have to tell it to reload it.)

Comment: Thanks for your advices and interesting reading. Many way to corrupt a SQLite db... It seems much better to use .restore command indeed.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again.